# Forbidden : You don't have permission to access /questions.php on this server

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css, apache

I am beginner in PHP and I got the Error for Developed My Project ERROR is Like:

**This: Forbidden**

You don't have permission to access /quiz.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Please give the suggestion for Solve this problem.

Comment: Please post the code of quiz.php

Comment: permission issue....give permission to file

Comment: What is the user the webserver runs under and what is the file permissions for `quiz.php`?

Comment: I am Using the Apache Server

Comment: i have developed the Core PHP Application i don't know why issue will be came...

Comment: Can you tell me how to give the permission for that file ( Naincy Gupta)

Answer (score 0):

From interpreting the error, I believe that the problem doesn't lie in php but rather in the underlying operating system and filesystem. More specifically, file permissions.

If you are running `Apache` on `Linux` the webserver will only be able to serve pages that it can read. This has to do with local filesystem permissions.

I'm taking a leap here, but if your server is run by the user `www-data` then that user needs `read` permissions to the `.php` files in order to serve them as web pages. If these files are in a subdirectory, then that subdirectory and the `.php` files inside must also be accessible by `www-data`.

First, make sure that `quiz.php` is readable by the user `www-data`, as most likely you would have created this file using a different user account (root? yourself?).

The following command sets the owner of the file `quiz.php` to `www-data`

> chown www-data quiz.php

This command needs to be issued in the directory where `quiz.php` is located and it needs to be entered with a user account that has sufficient privileges to change a file's attributes. Normally this is the root account, but it could be you if the server's administrator has given you those permissions.

You can read up on the `chown` command by typing

> man chown

on most `Linux` systems.